# Not sending emails for no data without using data driven subscription

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have sql server standard which does not support data driven subscription. As per my report requirement I don't want to send an email if there is no data.Is there any way I can do that without using data driven subscription.
Thanks!

Comment: Within the agent job use a query to check the dataset first, and if it contains no data, don't run the subscription. I.e. `IF EXISTS({Your Query}) EXEC ReportServer.dbo.AddEvent...`

Comment: Thanks a lot! The above answer is definitely helpful and I am going to implement the same. However my some report has parameter and there are multiple subscription based on the parameter.so the report might have data for the some parameters and might be empty for other parameters.

Comment: But you have different subscriptions with different parameters, so include those parameters in `{Your Query}`. Correct?

Comment: After reading about AddEvent procedure I understood  that It will  execute SSRS subscription not report.   Awesome! Thanks a lot:)

Comment: So after digging into it I have question is that How to find subscription ID in SQL Agent job? do I need admin rights for the same? Thanks!

Comment: That is one of the reasons why I never use the agent tasks created by SSRS. When editting the subscription in the web portal though, you can see it in the URL.

Comment: Its not showing for me.

Comment: Are you *sure*? It's there for every instance I've used, since 2008 (I can't comment for 2005, but if you're using 2005 why *are* you using 2005?)

Comment: Your URL will look something like `http://YourServer/Reports/Pages/SubscriptionProperties.aspx?ItemPath=%2fYourProject%2fYourReportd&IsDataDriven=False&SubscriptionID=eecbba4b-8352-43b1-a5a3-3ae33c7313ae...` Notice the subscriptionID at the end (that is actually mid URL but i wasn't pasting the whole thing).

Comment: I have 2012 but not showing .

Comment: Then you're looking in the wrong place, that redacted URL I pasted was from my 2012 instance. I can't really be more specific that it's when you're editting the subscription; as that is where you find it.

Comment: I finally could figure it out .Thanks!.I have one more question is how should I schedule SSRS report and sql agent job.That means if SSRS report is monthly 10:30 am then when should i schedule sql agent job.I am trying to understand how it will work.Thanks

Comment: Monthly could be a range of meaning. The Agent has a range of options on how you can schedule, I suggest having a look at those options and choosing accordingly.

Comment: Oh yes!Thanks alot!